# Passing the whole object with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

First of all, I'm using [**ui-router**](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/).

Actually I'm passing the *slug* through the `states` and it's working perfectly, as you can see below:

```
.state('pages', {
    url: '/:slug',
    template: '<page-content></page-content>'
})

<a ui-sref="pages({ slug: item.slug })" title="{{item.title}}" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.menu_items">{{ item.title }}</a>
```

This way I can get the slug in `$stateParams` and in URL. **However**, I want to send the whole `object` and keep the URL with the *slug*.

Below you can see my attempt:

The `config` of *states*:

```
.state('pages', {
    url: 'obj.slug', // -> What should I put here? (of course /:slug doesn't work anymore)
    template: '<page-content></page-content>',
    params: { obj: null }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<a ui-sref="pages({ obj: item })" title="{{item.title}}" ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.menu_items">{{ item.title }}</a>
```

It's working to passing the whole object through the states (I can get it using `$stateParams`), however I can't generate the URL dynamically.

An example of the `object`:

```
{
  id: 6480,
  title: "Test",
  slug: "test"
}
```

So, the question is:

Is there a way to generate a *url* from a property of the `object` using `params` (in that way that I'm doing)? Ex: 'site.com/test'? (`test` is the slug that I want to put in the URL)

Comment: set obj.slot to a varible outside the object literal, somthing like so, `var string = obj.slug` and then use this string in your object literal

Comment: @ZeRubeus, the configuration of states is performed only at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the URL definition once they're loaded.  You'll want to do something like

```
.state('pages', {
    url: '/pages/:slug', // -> What should I put here?
    template: '<page-content></page-content>',
    params: { obj: null }
})
```

Then use the "slug" part to figure out where to go from there, likely from the resolve property which will allow you to inject objects into your controller.

**Edit:**

Maybe this is more what you're looking for.

```
.state('pages', {
        url: '/:pageName' 
        template: '<page-content></page-content>',
        params: { obj: null }
    })
```

then you change state

```
$state.go('pages', {pageName: item.Name, obj: item});
```

I'm not sure how you'd necessarily go about doing that with ui-sref on an anchor tag.  Maybe this?

```
<a ui-sref="pages({pageName: item.Name, obj: item})"
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. I've already tried this, however it doesn't work. The url keeps without the slug. I added more context into my question. Take a look please.

Comment: @developer033 ok, that's a bit clearer.  I've updated the response.  If that doesn't do it then let's dump this in a plunk.

Comment: I manage it to work few minutes ago (exactly this way that you post in your answer), after many attempts, however I'll check your answer as correct. Thanks a lot for your time. Cheers :)

Comment: Just a note: I just noticed that if I insert the url by hand, ex: 'site.com/test', the id comes, however the `object`, of course, doesn't. I have to treat it also or it will bring a lot of errors in the future.

Comment: You'll want to check whether the object is there either in the controller or the routing so that you don't end up in an odd state.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641592/how-to-redirect-to-state-if-specific-stateparam-is-empty

Comment: The other option, and better imho, would be to try to resolve the data if not available.  Otherwise your URL isn't really representing an actual resource anymore and you'll likely lose the params on a refresh.  Just something to think about.

Comment: Yes, I'll see and choose the best option. Thanks more one time.